# google-closure-compiler basic process example

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, google-closure-compiler, uglifyjs

could anyone please add a snippet to a google-closure-compiler basic process, I am trying unsuccessfully to this via js code.
I am using the exmple snippet from the official npm page.
when I run it, something seem to happen but the output file isn't created.

My code:

```js
const ClosureCompiler = require('google-closure-compiler').jsCompiler;

console.log(ClosureCompiler.CONTRIB_PATH); // absolute path to the contrib folder which contains externs

const closureCompiler = new ClosureCompiler({
  compilation_level: 'ADVANCED'
});

const compilerProcess = closureCompiler.run([{
 path: './',
 src: 'a.js',
 sourceMap: null // optional input source map
}], (exitCode, stdOut, stdErr) => {
    console.log(stdOut)
  //compilation complete
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building from what you had, I've changed just a few things:

1) The `src` attribute is not a path it is the file: read the file in this case with fs.readFileSync.

2) The output is returned in the callback: you'll need to write it to the disk.

Files:

*index.js*

```
const ClosureCompiler = require('google-closure-compiler').jsCompiler;
const {writeFile, readFileSync} = require('fs');

const closureCompiler = new ClosureCompiler({
  compilation_level: 'ADVANCED'
});
let src = readFileSync('a.js', 'UTF-8');
const compilerProcess = closureCompiler.run([{
 path: './',
 src: src,
 sourceMap: null
}], (exitCode, stdOut, stdErr) => {
  stdOut.map((fileResults) => {
    writeFile(fileResults.path, fileResults.src, () => {});
  });
});
```

*a.js*

```
console.log('hello world!')
```

*compiled.js*

```
console.log("hello world!");
```

Comment: thnx, that helped a lot.I thought that the file could be created without using 'fs', since the official npm site shows how to do it using a cli snippet (npx google-closure-compiler --js=my_program.js --js_output_file=out.js)

Comment: I've just checked the code for the cli, and it looks like you'r right. even in the cli they use 'fs'.

Comment: @Graham how did you figure this out? The documentation on github for path lists a filename and and some random code for src https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-npm/blob/master/packages/google-closure-compiler/README.md#javascript-version-1

Comment: @jjrabbit iirc I looked at the internals for gulp-closure-compiler...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apperantly there is no way to create a file without using a 'fs' library.

according to the "closure-compiler-js.js", when "run" is complete, the callback only loggs out the result.
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-npm/blob/master/packages/google-closure-compiler/lib/node/closure-compiler-js.js

which is funnny, because 'closure-compiler-npm' does use 'fs' to read the file contents, but it dosent have any 'write-file' mechanism.

and even on the official 'cli.js' the 'fs' library is used:
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-npm/blob/master/packages/google-closure-compiler/cli.js

```js
const ClosureCompiler = require('google-closure-compiler').jsCompiler;
const { writeFile } = require('fs');

const closureCompiler = new ClosureCompiler({
    js:['a.js','a1.js'],
    js_output_file: 'out.js'
});

const compilerProcess = closureCompiler.run([{
    path: './',
}], (exitCode, stdOut, stdErr) => {
     writeFile(stdOut[0].path, stdOut[0].src,()=>{});
});
```